# scroll and pinch in multiple UiScrollViews at the same time

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have an `UICollectionView` with four custom cells. The cell's delegate is my main view which contains the collectionView and extends a custom cell delegate. Each cell contains a single `UIScrollView` which in turn contains and displays an `UIImageView`. For now, I can pinch and doubleTap to zoom in and out and move the image inside the cell's scrollViews.

I have in my application a "lock views" button that should lock the views together, so that if I pinch (zoom or move) in a cell, that change should be "copied" in the other cells. A 10% zoom increase in a cell should trigger a 10% zoom increase in all the others cells (independently to each cell current `zoomScale`). Similarly, a 10 unit movement to the left in one cell should move the others cells 10 units to the left.

I'm using `scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)` method to detect a change in my scrollViews and call my delegate which in turn have access to my others cells in my main `UICollectionView`

My first problem was that when I used `UIScrollView.zoom(to : rect)` or `UIScrollView.zoomScale` it would trigger again `scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)` in the others cells thus creating some king of infinite loop, but I managed to fix that by using :

```
var isZooming = false

func scrollViewCustomZoom(to rect: CGRect, animated : Bool ) {
        isZooming = true
        scrollView.zoom(to: rect, animated: animated)
        isZooming = false
    }
```

And :

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if isZooming { return }
        // do stuff, typically call the delegate
    }
```

But now my problem is : what do I need to calculate in my `scrollViewDidScroll` method, and what do I need to set in each cell in my delegate in order you have the behavior I'm looking for?

I've already tried to play around `scrollView.bounds`, `scrollView.origin` or `scrollView.size`, but couldn't get the scaling factor to behave properly.

Any help would be most welcome and appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to my own question. This solution does not call `scrollViewDidScroll()` in the others cells, which is exactly what I wanted.

Here is the trick :

```
// pinch-pan detection :
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let newOrigin = scrollView.bounds.origin
    let dx = newOrigin.x - currentScrollViewOrigin.x
    let dy = newOrigin.y - currentScrollViewOrigin.y

    let newScale = scrollView.zoomScale
    let ds = newScale - currentZoomScale

    if let d = delegate{
        d.notifyMouvementInCell(self, dx: dx, dy: dy, ds: ds)
    }

    currentScrollViewOrigin = scrollView.bounds.origin
    currentZoomScale = scrollView.zoomScale
}
```

In my delegate :

```
func notifyMouvementInCell(_ cell: customCell, dx: CGFloat, dy: CGFloat, ds: CGFloat){
    if areViewsLocked{
        for visibleCell in collectionView.visibleCells as! [IMECasesMultiDisplayCollectionViewCell]{
            if visibleCell == cell { continue }
            visibleCell.copyMouvementInForeignCell(horOffset: dx, vertOffset: dy, scaleOffset: ds)
        }
    }
}
```

And back in my cells :

```
func copyMouvementInForeignCell(horOffset dx: CGFloat, vertOffset dy: CGFloat, scaleOffset ds: CGFloat){
    var newOrigin = scrollView.bounds.origin
    newOrigin.x += dx
    newOrigin.y += dy
    scrollView.bounds.origin = newOrigin

    var newScale = scrollView.zoomScale
    newScale += ds
    let affineTrans = CGAffineTransform(a: newScale, b: 0, c: 0, d: newScale, tx: 0, ty: 0)
    // imageView is the view contained in each of my cell's scrollViews
    imageView.layer.setAffineTransform(affineTrans)

    currentZoomScale = scrollView.zoomScale
    currentScrollViewOrigin = scrollView.bounds.origin
}
```

Hope this will help somebody someday !